# Get child model from parent class

Tags: java, activerecord, reflection

I've to create a simple self-made ActiveRecord class for my project.

Only stuck on the problem that I have a `getModel()` in my `Player` class, which is being extended by a `ActiveRecord` class.

When I want to use the `getModel()` method from my `ActiveRecord` class, I cant use it cause it's not the same type. I don't want to reference `Player` here, because I want to use multiple models.

Anyone has a solution?

Ok so I got something up:

```
abstract class ActiveRecord<T> {
   private T model;

   public T getModel() {
     return this.model;
   }
}

public class Player extends ActiveRecord<Player> {
}

public class Event extends ActiveRecord<Event> {
}
```

But when I try to output `this.model` in my `ActiveRecord` class, it return `null`.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the content of the two classes?

Comment: I've added examples.

Comment: From what you've posted there's no justification for an Abstract class.  You'll need to provide actual code.  There's just not enough to go on.

Comment: Editted my examples. Does is make more sense now?
I have multiple models which do need the ActiveRecord functions, executed on the given model/child.

Comment: So you basically want to have a class 'Player' that contains a 'Player' object named 'model'?  This doesn't make much sense.  Also, you never instantiate 'model', so it will always return NULL.

Comment: I've changed it up. Try to make a repository, way more simple I guess. Take a look, got a question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226955/dbrepository-implementation-without-constructor-in-child-classes)

Comment: Why don't you just use `getClass()` to find out which class your `ActiveRecord` actually is?

Answer (score 1):

Your method definition needs to do something like this

```
public Class<? extends ActiveRecord> getModel();
```

Meaning of this is that the return type is of class that extends ActiveRecord. When you do this to the child it would return Player.class as Player extends ActiveRecord.

A brief note if getModel return an object of that class then you should remove Class from the method function

```
public <? extends ActiveRecord> getModel();
```

Comment: But the return type could be different, as I have multiple models who will use the ActiveRecord class.

Comment: So in my child I've got to use **public <? extends ActiveRecord> getModel() { // logic }}** and in my parent class (ActiveRecord) I would have **abstract <? extends ActiveRecord> getModel();** ?

Comment: Now what is Eloquent class ?

Comment: Sorry I meant ActiveRecord.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62544/discussion-between-guidsen-and-wronganswer).

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well you have a super class called ActiveRecord and a subclass Player, which has a method getModel.

If you want to use ActiveRecord as reference type then you need to have a getModel method in that class as well if you want to access that method. If you are never going to instantiate an ActiveRecord as such you can make it abstract and define the getModel method abstract. If you don't have any implementation logic in ActiveRecord you could make it an interface as well.

```
public abstract class ActiveRecord {
  public abstract Model getModel();
}

public class Player extends ActiveRecord {
  @Override
  public Model getModel() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've used a bit of reflection. Implemented getModel() in ActiveRecord, which returns getClass(). Would this be a good solution?

Comment: Don't make it too hard if you don't need to. Could you share some code in your question?

Comment: Added new situation. Would appreciate if u could take a look on it.

Comment: You never instantiated the model value. It seems you want to return the Player object itself. But that is completely contradictory to polymorphism to do that kind of thing. Do you have a use case for what you are tyring to do?

Comment: Im trying to create a basic ActiveRecord class, where I can do something like: **Player player = new Player; player.setFirstName("John"); player.save();** and it will save itself to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're making life way too hard for yourself. Java already does reflection for you.

```
class Parent {
    // class content
}

class ChildA extends Parent {
    // class content
}

class ChildB extends Parent {
    // class content
}

Parent firstInstance = new ChildA();
Parent secondInstance = new ChildB();

Class typeOfFirst = firstInstance.getClass();
Class typeOfSecond = secondInstance.getClass();
```

As for your `null` pointer error, in Java (Unlike c++ for example) you have to explicitly initialise every variable with `new`. Just having `private T model;` doesn't create an instance of it.