# DbRepository implementation without constructor in child classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I got the following objects:

```
public class DbRepository<T> implements DbRepositoryInterface<T>{
  protected T model;

  protected DbRepository(T model) {
    System.out.println("DbRepository created.");
    this.model = model;
  }

  @Override
  public T getModel() {
    return model;
  }
}

public interface DbRepositoryInterface<T> {
  public T getModel();
}

public class PlayerDbRepository extends DbRepository<Player> {
}
```

In my code, where I want to make use of the `PlayerDbRepository` I would like to call:

```
DbRepositoryInterface<Player> repo = new PlayerDbRepository();
```

But in the `PlayerDbRepository` I get a warning about my constructor in the parent class `DbRepository`. What do I have to modify to make this work? Or is my approach on this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `DbRepository` class has a required constructor that takes a `T`.  Since your `PlayerDbRepository` subclasses this `DbRepository`, you must call the parent constructor with a `T` instance.

You can do this 2 ways:

1. making a similar constructor in the child class that takes a Player and delegates it to the parent constructor:

   ```
   public class PlayerDbRepository extends DbRepository<Player> {

      public PlayerDbRepository(Player model){
          super(model);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Create a Player instance some other way and pass it in

   ```
   public class PlayerDbRepository extends DbRepository<Player> {

      public PlayerDbRepository(){
          super(new Player());
      }
   }
   ```

Of course you can always combine both solutions so users of the code can choose which option is best for them.

```
 public class PlayerDbRepository extends DbRepository<Player> {
       /**
       * Creates new Repository with default Player.
       */
       public PlayerDbRepository(){
           super(new Player());
       }

       /**
       * Creates new Repository with given Player.
       */
       public PlayerDbRepository(Player model){
           super(model);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

DbRepositoryInterface is interface.

You cannot create an interface object.

One thing you can do is by implementing Factory class, to map your interface with your repository classes. Normally we use tools to do that.

Your instantiation would then be like below:
DbRepositoryInterface repo = FactoryClass.GetInstanceOf();
which in turn, you will return PlayerDbRepository object anyway.

Thank you,

Comment: You can create an interface object by creating a class or anonymous class that implements the interface.  Adding extra layers like factories to the problem doesn't make the OP's question go away, it just pushes it down another layer.

Comment: You are correct. Then, try to add another empty parameter constructor on your parent class.
public DbRepository() { }
should do the trick.